# tabWidget проблема

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь в tabWidget сделать так что бы при переходе с на следующую страницу то зажатые кнопки сбрасывались в начальное состояние "отжимались".
Но у меня выходит ошибка

C:\WORK\Examples\SEntember1\MA_Check\mainwindow.cpp:1839: ошибка: C2248: QAbstractButton::toggled: невозможно обратиться к protected член, объявленному в классе "QAbstractButton"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtgui../../src/gui/widgets/qabstractbutton.h(128): см. объявление "QAbstractButton::toggled"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtgui../../src/gui/widgets/qabstractbutton.h(58): см. объявление "QAbstractButton"

И теперь не знаю как быть ((( . Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
     #include "mainwindow.h"
      #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

      MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

       MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
    delete ui;
 }
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

ui->ciklButton_1->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_2->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_3->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_9->setEnabled(true);
}

 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_toggled(bool checked)
{
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
ui->ciklButton_1->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_2->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_3->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_9->setEnabled(true);
}


 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_toggled(bool checked)
{
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);
ui->ciklButton_1->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_2->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_3->setEnabled(true);
ui->ciklButton_9->setEnabled(true);
}
  void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
  {
     if(index)
  {
    ui->pushButton->toggled(false);
    ui->pushButton_2->toggled(false);
    ui->pushButton_3->toggled(false);
   }
   else
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Поправьте теги, C# тут явно лишний...
При нажатии на кнопки они переходят в состояние "disable"?
Судя по ошибке это состояние кнопка может менять только сама себе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем мужики разобрался , но только двумя нажатиями на кнопку то пройдет на другую закладку (надо слегка допилить), а так вот код

```
   void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
   {
      if (index)
      {
        ui->pushButton->setAutoExclusive(false);
        ui->pushButton->setChecked(false);
        ui->pushButton->setAutoExclusive(true);
        //--
        ui->pushButton_2->setAutoExclusive(false);
        ui->pushButton_2->setChecked(false);
        ui->pushButton_2->setAutoExclusive(true);
        //--
        ui->pushButton_3->setAutoExclusive(false);
        ui->pushButton_3->setChecked(false);
        ui->pushButton_3->setAutoExclusive(true);
      }
   }
```

Comment: У вас либо опечатка, либо ошибка в коде: в первом блоке функция `ui->pushButton->setAutoExclusive(false);` дважды вызывается cо значением `false`.

Comment: спасибо , исправил

Answer (score 0):

Внимательнее читайте документацию: `void toggled(bool)` - это **сигнал**.

Здесь `ui->pushButton->toggled(false);` вы пытаетесь извне заставить объект класса `QPushButton` запустить сигнал. По идеологии Qt сигналы могут быть вызваны только непосредственно самим объектом (т.е. в коде, реализующем класс этого объекта).

Для переключения состояния кнопки класс `QAbstractButton` имеет метод `void toggle()`. Этот метод изменяет свойство `checked` на противоположное. Или используйте метод `setChecked(bool)` - он меняет свойство `checked` на указанное.

Правильный код в вашем случае:

```
void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{
  if(index) {
    ui->pushButton->setChecked(false);
    ui->pushButton_2->setChecked(false);
    ui->pushButton_3->setChecked(false);
  }
}
```

И кстати, проверка `if(index)` вероятно неправильна. Выбранный индекс у `QTabWidget` может быть равным 0, тогда код внутри секции `if` выполнен не будет.

Comment: Так не работает .